# Machine won't boot - drive order changed

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot

So, we have a beefy Dell fileserver, a bunch of drives in some raid config, and a small root/boot drive.  All fine and good, now the boot drive which was /dev/sda is now /dev/sdq and the machine won't boot.  Nothing changed hardware wise.

How can I restore this drive to be /dev/sda and then be able to boot? what determines drive order?  This is drive number 15 (like I said, beefy fileserver), but somehow it was /dev/sda before and /dev/sdq now.  Other machines with the same hardware config still have a drive still as /dev/sda

I forget the model number, but it's new enough to have the iDRAC9 Management Hardware

Comment: Set the boot order in the BIOS. Why wasn't the OS intsalled with UEFI? This would have prevented the problem.